# How to listen HashMap value changes in separate thread making it Flowable?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I have Map of items I want to listen to changes and make some actions 
and I want to do it in separate thread, but the map is changed but I could listen to it changes

```
val removedItemList: HashMap<Int,Item> = HashMap()

Flowable.fromArray(removedShoppingList.values).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe({ items ->
      Log.i("items_removed", " " + items + items.size);
    })
```

Comment: It depends on what and how do you want to be notified. Intercepting Map method calls by wrapping removeListItem into a custom class and using `PublishSubject`(s) for various change events. Note though that HashMap is not thread safe so signalling the entire map to a separate thread or just reading from it in other threads is dangerous.

Comment: Ok ,I see , what do you think to change it to ConcurentHashMap?
And what you mean "how do you want to be notified?"

Comment: Items can be added, removed, replaced through a few dozen methods, which ones do you want to detect?

Comment: I need to listen changes when items are added or removed from removedShoppingList,
I need to keep HashMap and PublishSubject of HashMap adding to HashMap and listening to that changes via PublishSubject
I don't have clear idea how I should implement it ,  
What do you think ConcurrentHashMap could be the alternative of HashMap?

Comment: You can use `ObservableMap` inJavaFX property package. (If javafx is accessible in android environment)

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following code:

```
// When HashMap changed, this class emitted.
class MapEvent(val event: EventType, val item: Item?){
    enum class EventType {
        ADD,
        REMOVE
    }
}
```

~~~

```
// PublishSubject emits changed event.
val subject = PublishSubject.create<MapEvent>()

// Subscribe changed event.
// When emits changed event by PublishSubject, print log.
val obervable = subject.hide().share()
obervable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe {it -> Log.i("HashMap Changed", "Event: ${it.event}, Item: ${it.item}")}

val itemList: HashMap<Int, Item> = HashMap()
val addedItem = Item()

// If you add or remove HashMap item, then execute onNext method in order to emit changed event.
itemList.put(1, addedItem)
subject.onNext(MapEvent(MapEvent.EventType.ADD, addedItem))
val removedItem = itemList.remove(1)
subject.onNext(MapEvent(MapEvent.EventType.REMOVE, removedItem))
```